# VS2019 Warning message - C4121 - alignment of a member was sensitive to packing

Tags: c++, mfc, migration, visual-studio-2019

After Converted VS2008 to VS2019 getting this warning messages

Warning C4121   'JOBOBJECT_IO_RATE_CONTROL_INFORMATION_NATIVE_V2': alignment of a member was sensitive to packing.

Warning C4121   'JOBOBJECT_IO_RATE_CONTROL_INFORMATION_NATIVE_V3': alignment of a member was sensitive to packing.

and target path is showing to this file C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\um\winnt.h

Converted version is 16.7.6

How can I remove or disable these warning messages.

Comment: You can silence any warning on the command line, though don't you want to understand what this warning means first?

Answer (score 0):

You could input `4121` in `Properties->C/C++->Advanced->Disable Specific Warnings` to disable `C4121`.

[image]

Also, you could refer to Microsoft Docs about [C4121](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-warnings/compiler-warning-level-4-c4121?view=vs-2019).

C4121: `symbol : alignment of a member was sensitive to packing`

The compiler added padding to align a structure member on the packing boundary but the packing value is less than the member's size.

This warning only happens when the compiler adds padding before data members. It does not happen when packing has placed data at a memory location that is not aligned for the data type, but no padding was placed before the data member. When data is not aligned on boundaries that are multiples of the data's size, performance can degrade. Reads and writes of unaligned data cause processor faults on some architectures and the faults may take two or three orders of magnitude more time to resolve. Unaligned data accesses cannot be ported to some RISC architectures.

You can use [#pragma pack](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/pack?view=vs-2019) or [/Zp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/zp-struct-member-alignment?view=vs-2019) to specify the structure alignment. (The compiler does not generate this warning when /Zp1 is specified.)